# Why do if-elses, which are said to have no effect when calculating time complexity, create a time difference?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

When I test the running speed of the code below, it takes 26 seconds in the worst-case and takes 1 second in the best-case. But ,according to Big-O notation: it's a O(1) and
** O(1)— Constant Complexity**
No matter how large the dataset you have in Constant complexity, the time to run and the resource used are always constant.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

            

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                string x = "aafdsggfjjrffdfhgfhgjfdgfdgfr";
                string y = string.Empty;
                if (x.Contains("rghfjgkhhj"))
                {
                    y = "fdsfdsfds";
                }
                else if (x.Contains("rghfjgkhhj"))
                {
                    y = "fdsfdsfds";
                }
                else if (x.Contains("rghfjgkhhj"))
                {
                    y = "fdsfdsfds";
                }
                else if (x.Contains("rghfjgkhhj"))
                {
                    y = "fdsfdsfds";
                }
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                500 times
                else if (x.Contains("rghfjgkhhj"))
                {
                    y = "fdsfdsfds";
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

So , since it is o(1) there is no time difference then why 26 seconds difference?
(Please don't comment if you don't know how to calculate time complexity.
)

Comment: `.Contains()` will be `O(n)`. I don't know where you're getting the `O(1)` complexity here.

Comment: String's ```Contains``` goes with O(n) for its size. Of course the size here is constant so you could argue it is O(1). In any case, even if it is O(1), it is O(1) times 500 times 10000. That's O(n) is my book. Or O(n*m) for an n-sized string with m calls to ```Contains```

Comment: Time complexity is a way to measure code in abstract terms, to learn how a piece of code might be affected by different constraints. But it's not directly translatable to actual runtime of the code. All that can be said from the time complexity is that one algorithm will take longer or shorter than another algorithm with another different complexity.

Comment: As for the actual runtime, *all* code will add to the actual runtime of your program. An expression might not affect the complexity, but it will take actual time to compute when running.

Comment: *Who* says that `if`/`else` statements don't affect the time complexity? Please provide a citation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by the user [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude), time complexity is just abstract as it sounds - it does not tell you how long in seconds (or any time measurement in that case) the code will finish running, but to give it an abstract evaluation of how good/worst it handles input according to its size.

Not to mention the actual running time is affected by other factors such as:

- Memory allocation speed
- Clock rate of the CPU
  and much more.

The size can be anything you base your methods on: length of an array, length of a string, number of bytes to process etc..

In this case, you measure your `O` by the number of iterations you're doing in the `for` loop.

Here everything is a constant:

- The number of iterations of the `for-loop`.
- Number of `if` statements.
- The first string's length.
- Other strings also have constant lengths.

So you're correct - your function does not make any use of its input (`args`), thus does not rely on how scalable it is (for good and bad).

However, it does not mean `O(1)` runs as fast as `O(10000)`, surely they are in the same complexity group - (`O(1)`) but they will **not** finish running at the same time!

Here you're doing 500 million iterations that check if one string is included in the other string, that of-course will be much slower than just doing 1 million iterations, or 100 million iterations, by these according (roughly) factors (~X500, ~X5).
Although they are all in the same "mathematical" set - `O(1)`.

Comment: You said that: 
'In this case, you measure your O by the number of iterations you're doing in the for loop.'
-But  In link below , even there is more if-else condition and increase lenght in for , it' doesn'matter.Both are O(1) 
https://shunnarski.github.io/BigO.html
 -and I learnt O(n+1) equals to O(n) and  ,we should avoid use loop ,  each if condiiton is +1 and it's not reason for time slow  from data structures course.

you compared ' O(1) and O(10000)' , what about comparing O(n+500) and O(n+10)?

Comment: Again, they are in the same mathematical set, but they will run in different times, as the input is larger (talking about growth in runtime as the input gets larger) both of your code and some other code is in the set `O(1)` - it does **not** mean they will run the same.

Comment: Okay I get you , so what is the  O(1) meaning?how can they are in the mathematical set?

Comment: I'd suggest you to read the formal definition of big-o notation, here: https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html